# Geting Error Unable to Focus element

Tags: javascript, selenium, dynamics-crm-2013

I am automating some page in Microsoft CRM 2013 version. I am able to open the entity and type the value in search field , but when i am trying to click on serach result i am getting error " Unable to focus element", where as the XPATh is correct and i am able to verify it in firepath.

I have switched the frame as well. Currently using chrome driver.Tried using Action class as well.

Please find the code :

```
driver1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='crmGrid_findCriteria']")).sendKeys(OrderID);
                driver1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='crmGrid_findCriteria']")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
                driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Actions actions = new Actions(driver1);
                 actions.moveToElement(driver1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gridBodyTable']/tbody/tr/td[2]/nobr[@class = 'gridcellpadding' and @title = 'ORD-CBLCO0018710']/a")));
                 actions.click();
                 actions.build().perform();
```

Comment: are you getting the error while using `Actions` class or without it ?

Comment: i am getting error in both the cases. (with Actions and without Actions)

Comment: can you share site url ?

Comment: Instead of `sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);` can you invoke `click()` on any clickable button?

Comment: i am not able to click on any element, that's why i have used sendkeys to press enter.

Comment: URL can not be shared as this wont work on public network.